# PREDICATE logic: how to formalize "it is important that Alf comes or that Betty comes"

Tags: logic

"It is important that Alf comes or that Betty comes".

What would be correct formalization of the above statement? Here is my attempt (I would use a predicate language where "being important" = I, Alf comes = a and Betty comes = b):

Ia V Ib

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Importantly, for this question you're talking about *second order logic* ($I$ is a predicate that acts on the *sentences* "Alf comes" and "Betty comes"). That should color how you interpret the answers to your other question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963771/why-px-v-y-and-px-v-py-are-not-logically-equivalent/2963870#2963870

Answer (score 1):

"It is important that" is a sort-of-modal operator, operating on sentences. It is not a predicate operating on singular terms, and the language of predicate logic lacks modal operators on sentences.

Put $A$ for Alf comes, and $B$ for Betty comes. Then you presumably want $\Box(A \lor B)$.

That is not in general equivalent to $(\Box A \lor \Box B)$.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want is $I(a\lor b)$, because $Ia\lor Ib$ means "It's important Alf comes, or it's important Betty comes", which probably isn't what you meant.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But this is logically equivalent to Ia ∨ Ib right?

Comment: Actually, in fact, are you sure that I(a∨b) is a well-formed formula? And if it is, why?

Comment: @Mijito Of course it is. Say they're two friends, either one of whom could serve you to the same end. You're in trouble only if neither turns up, i.e. it's important at least one of them does. But neither individual arrival is important, because it wouldn't be needed if the other one happens.

Comment: So yes I(a∨b) is a well-formed formula and yes, the two formulas are logically equivalent?

Comment: No, they're not. You'll find predicates of propositions generally don't satisfy $X(a\lor b)\equiv Xa\lor Xb$. For example, "Carol knows $a$ or $b$" doesn't imply "Carol knows $a$, or Carol knows $b$".

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't see why "Carol knows a or b" doesn't imply "Carol knows a, or Carol knows b".

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @Mijito To take an extreme example, consider $b=\neg a$.

Comment: I still don't see why "Carol knows a or b" doesn't imply "Carol knows a, or Carol knows b", sorry for being so slow :-)!

Comment: @Mijito Do you know $a\lor\neg a$? [Sure you do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_excluded_middle). Do you either know $a$, or know $\neg a$? Not if you're unsure whether $a$ is true or not!

Comment: Ok, that's a really intuitive explanation. However, I'll still ask a question on this topic, because the logical reasons are still unclear to me.

Comment: Actually, as I suggested, maybe I(a∨b) is not a well-formed formula! See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963771/why-px-v-y-and-px-v-py-are-not-logically-equivalent