# Why P(x V y) and Px V Py are not logically equivalent?

Tags: logic

I'm struggling to understand why the following sentence of a predicate language

$P(x\lor y)$

is not logically equivalent to the sentence

$Px\lor Py$

If this is indeed the case (i.e. the two sentences are not equivalent) could someone explain why (in terms, for instance, of satisfaction of assignments in a model?)

Comment: What is $P$? Why do you have two variables with a disjunction between? The top expression doesn't even look like a well formed formula.

Comment: P could be any predicate (such as "knowing", "being sad") etc. However, I was also wondering whether the top expression actually is a well-formed formula. Would it be if there were individual constants instead of variables? I don't think so, because synctactically the formula would be the same...

Comment: Actually what made me ask this question is the answer I received to this other question (in fact, I don't think the answer I received is a good one; I'm very confused now!): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963518/basic-logic-how-to-formalize-it-is-important-that-alf-comes-or-that-betty-come/2963524?noredirect=1#comment6118500_2963524

Comment: It looks like the person in that post is using "it's important that" not as a predicate, but as a modal operator (something that takes propositions as inputs and outputs a new proposition). Which is a non-standard thing to have in predicate logic.

Comment: In order for us to show why something isn't the case, you have to tell us why you think it is.  We can't correct a wrong argument that you are keeping secret.

Comment: ["predicate language"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) can mean either first order logic or higher order logic: in the first case, $x$ and $y$ are usually used to denote "objects" (individuals) and the $\lor$ is a propositional connective, acting on frmulas and not objects.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ acts on propositions, $P(x\lor y)$ is well-formed because $x\lor y$ is well-defined. But in general, $P(x\lor y)$ doesn't imply $Px\lor Py$. For example, suppose $Px$ means $x$ is a theorem. Then $P(x\lor y)$ means you can prove $x\lor y$, as for example is possible if $y=\neg x$. But in that case: [if you can't prove or disprove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(mathematical_logic)) $x$, the former fact implies $\neg Px$ while the latter implies $\neg Py$.

Comment: But I mean, P(x∨y) is not a well-formed formula of predicate logic! As far as I know, concepts such as "well-defined" do not intervene there...

Comment: Also, in predicate logic textbooks I never encountered formulations like "P acts on propositions"...

Comment: @Mijito In $Px$, what kind of thing is $x$ meant to be? That's what $P$ acts on. If it's propositions, $x\lor y$ exists, so can be taken as an argument of the same unary predicate. The parentheses are just for clarity.

Comment: In fact, I should have specified from the beginning that my question concerns PREDICATE logic.

Comment: I know that x∨y exists but I don't think that's enough for P(x∨y) to be a well-formed formula?? Actually, I never encountered a formula like that one in logic textbooks...

Answer (score 1):

In ordinary language 'or' can conjoin expressions of various types, sentences, names, verbs, adverbs, etc. ('Romeo loves Rosalind or he loves Juliet', 'Romeo loves Rosalind or Juliet', 'Romeo loves or hates Juliet', 'Romeo loves Juliet wisely or unwisely', etc.)

But in the standard language of the predicate calculus, $\lor$ remains always and only a sentential connective -- i.e. it can only connect complete wffs (open or closed sentences).

So if $x$, $y$ are individual variables, and $P$ a predicate, $Px$ and $Py$ are wffs, and $(Px \lor Py)$ is a wff. But $(x \lor y)$ is simply ill-formed, and hence $P(x \lor y)$ is ill-formed too. Such are the rules of the game.

[Ah, you might say, couldn't we add a non-standard rule to the effect that $\varphi(x \lor y)$ is equivalent to $(\varphi x \lor \varphi y)$? But applied generally to simple or complex predicates, this could cause havoc. For then e.g. $\neg P(x \lor y)$ would have two different and non-equivalent readings depending on the order we apply the negation and the non-standard rule.]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer; this is exactly what I was looking for. So, concerning this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963518/predicate-logic-how-to-formalize-it-is-important-that-alf-comes-or-that-betty/2963524#2963524 I guess my attempt is correct?

Comment: See my response to that other question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're having some confusion about the use of symbols. You seem to be talking about *first order logic*, in which $x$, $y$, and similar variables are taken to represent objects. $\vee$ means "or", and importantly **does not mean what we typically mean by "or" in English**. It is much more limited; $\vee$ is an operation that produces a sentence which may be true or false. "Apple or orange" has no truth value, so it doesn't make sense to replace that "or" with $\vee$ - even though in English we commonly say things like "would you like apple or orange juice?"

$P(x \vee y)$ is itself nonsense, because it doesn't mean what you think it means when you read it - it looks like it's saying "$P$ holds of either $x$ or $y$". But that isn't what $\vee$ means; $P(x \vee y)$ would be more accurately read as "$P$ holds of the phrase '$x$ or $y$'". That's nonsense, unless $P$ is a predicate that acts on sentences and $x$ and $y$ are themselves sentences (see J.G.'s answer) in which case you're working in *second order logic*.

By contrast, $Px \vee Py$ is read as "Either $P$ holds of $x$ or $P$ holds of $y$" - which seems a bit long-winded, but *is* a correct translation of $\vee$, because the result is a sentence which may be either true or false.